# How do I get the logged user ID?

Tags: forms

I am developing a module with a form to ask for the email frequency; when users choose a value, and save it, I store it in the *users* table, but it doesn't work. It works only when I hard code the user ID.

```php
global $user;
$uuid = $user->uid;

function emailf_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $bb = $form_state['values']['emailf'];
  $query = db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('email_f' => $bb))
    ->condition('uid', $uuid, '=')
    ->execute(); 

  drupal_set_message('Email frequency successfully changed');  
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving the lines setting `$uuid` inside the function?

Comment: nop that's it when i set it inside the function it's working ...thanks...

Comment: Without the `global $uuid;` line, that code doesn't work. That variable should then be initialized from a function. Anyway, this is a plain PHP question. Drupal doesn't change how global variables work.

Answer (score 2):

It works when `$uuid` is initialized inside the function.

```
function emailf_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $uuid = $user->uid;

  $bb = $form_state['values']['emailf'];
  $query = db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('email_f' => $bb))
    ->condition('uid', $uuid, '=')
    ->execute(); 

  drupal_set_message('Email frequency successfully changed');  
}
```